# Can i access the metamask using Selenium Webdriver.

Tags: selenium, testing, frameworks, blockchain, metamask

For one of my projects, i am doing an integration testing. 
I have done the UI Automation, API Automation and Performance testing.
But i also want to test the the backend i.e. the blockchain side of the project, where i want to test whether the actual cryptocurrency got transferred or not.
So do we have any provision to automate the Metamask plugin using any test framework?